# getIdentifier() method in Java creates identifier field?

Tags: java, json, jackson, getter

In Java, I have a class in which there is a public `getIdentifier()` method which returns a string. When I serialize an instance of this class using jackson--an identifier field appears in the resulting json string. I have no declared `identifier` field in my class--just the `getIdentifier` function. Does having a `get@#%%()` function in Java automatically create a field named @#%%--or is Jackson possibly creating the field itself when serializing the object? Is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does having a get@#%%() function in Java automatically create a field named @#%%--or is Jackson possibly creating the field itself when serializing the object? Is there a way to get around this?

That's not the work of Java, I can assure that. Jackson is the culprit here, it will use all your getter methods to serialize the object into a JSON string. If you don't want this, you should use [`@JsonIgnore`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnore.html) Jackson annotation.

```
public class Foo {
    //my fields go here...
    //getters for each field go here as well...

    //now this method will be ignored for Jackson JSON serialization
    @JsonIgnore
    public String getIdentifier() {
        //fancy code that returns an identifier
    }
}
```